How can I use a freely scalable colorbar for 3 contourplots with matplotlib?
I am trying to get some printable graphics out of my ML project. Therefore I'd like to show the impact of a single variable (c) on three different contour plots (y over x) on a dependent variable (L). The minmum should be 0.5, the maximum should be 1.3.
My code is below
# For Stack overflow
# width & dimension of plot
total_width_mm = 190
total_width_inch = total_width_mm / 25.4
subplot_width_inch = total_width_inch /3
subplot_height_inch = subplot_width_inch

total_height_inch = subplot_height_inch

# Figure
fig, axes = plt.subplots(
    nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(total_width_inch, total_height_inch)
)

# Scale
vmin, vmax = 0.5 , 1.3

# Contourplots
cb = axes[0].contourf(X_grid, Y_grid, L_grid_up, levels=20, cmap='viridis', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
axes[1].contourf(X_grid, Y_grid, L_grid_mid, levels=20, cmap='viridis', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
axes[2].contourf(X_grid, Y_grid, L_grid_low, levels=20, cmap='viridis', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)

# Tilte & Axes
axes[0].set_title("c = 50")
axes[1].set_title("c = 150")
axes[2].set_title("c = 250")

axes[0].set_ylabel("y")
axes[1].set_xlabel("x")

axes[1].set_ylabel('')
axes[1].set_yticklabels([])

axes[2].set_ylabel('')
axes[2].set_yticklabels([])

# Colorbar
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.85)
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.87, 0.15, 0.03, 0.7])  # Position der Farbskala
colorbar = fig.colorbar(cb, cax=cbar_ax, label="L")


# Subplots "a", "b", "c" 
labels = ["a)", "b)", "c)"]
for ax, label in zip(axes, labels):
    ax.text(
        -0.1, 1.1, label, transform=ax.transAxes, fontsize=12, fontweight='bold',
        va='top', ha='left'
    )

plt.show()

I am getting this result
Output Colorbar
I was hoping to have a full scale colorbar from vmin to vmax
I found this question How to have one colorbar for all subplots
However, I was unable to use the paths forward there. Whatever I am doing gives me the colorbar limited to the mins and max of the first subplot. Changing the subplots into a different order would be not appropriate.
What am I doing wrong in specifying the colobar?

Apparently, when levels= is provided to contourf, vmin and vmax are ignored.  You could try levels=np.linspace(vmin, vmax, 21) to have the same levels for each subplot (necessary for them to be able to have the same colorbar).
